# Javascript & Next.js - TypeError with Object property after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, next.js, blockchain

I try to to check for an established connection to a wallet and, if connected, an object's property should be logged.

```
if (status == "WALLET_NOT_CONNECTED") { 
  console.log(status);
  } 
else { 
  var objFromWallets = wallets[0];
  console.log(objFromWallets);
  var a = objFromWallets.design.toString();
  console.log(a);
  }
```

This works but as soon as I refresh the page, I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'design')
  32 | 
  33 |   
> 34 |   var a = objFromWallets.design.toString();
     |                         ^
  35 |   console.log(a);
  36 |   
  37 |
```

My understanding is that the property "design" is not defined anymore after the page refresh. I don't know why ... maybe it takes time for the properties to get defined. How could I debug this?

Comment: Where is `wallets[0]` defined?

Comment: right before the if-statement: `export default function ConnectSample() {
  const {
    status,
    network,
    wallets,
    availableConnectTypes,
    availableInstallTypes,
    availableConnections,
    supportFeatures,
    connect,
    install,
    disconnect,
  } = useWallet();`

Comment: In that case you can use the `||` in javascript, if you are using react they have specific format on that, in vue I mostly use `((objFromWallets || {}). design || ''). toString()`, this example states that if `objFromWallets` is undefined or null or not an object, then set its value as `{}` (empty object) so the you can still use it as object then do the dot notation for `design` property, so when the design is not present on the object then assign a value of `''` (empty string)

Comment: @Forbidden this is exactly what I was looking for. It is working, thanks. But I still wonder why that is the case... I checked the imports for some clues but I cannot read the code that good. Would you mind having a look at it?

Comment: Sorry Im not totattly good at React, Im a Vue developer as of now, but base on my experience, in vue, there are times that data by default, especially component properties has a value of null, so to solve the issues I have to use the above solution. because the data will only be filled when an update happen. Glad it helps mate :)

Comment: Assuming `useWallet` is a hook, then the issue probably happens because when Next.js pre-renders the page on the server the `wallets` value must be an empty array (most likely its default value?). You should move any operation with `wallets` inside a `useEffect` call to ensure it only happens on the client-side, when `useWallet` actually returns the expected value for `wallets`.